# Do my tomatoes look like they are damaged from herbicides?

Tags: tomatoes, herbicide

I planted my healthy tomato starts that I started myself in some new soil that has alpaca manure mixed in.  The original, old growth is fine, but the new growth is all spindly and twisty and curling leaves. After researching the symptoms, I’m worried this is not a virus but is caused from herbicides, though the alpaca farm that I got the manure from claim they use no herbicides whatsoever, and they grow their own hay. We are completely organic and pretty isolated as far as any possible herbicide drift from the wind.  Can anyone help me identify the problem?  Any input is appreciated.  Thanks.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VUCj.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VUCj.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l34OM.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I have posted similar questions and sadly have experience with this.  Sorry for the  bad news.  Curled leaves is one thing, but when they are super dense and leathery like that, I have full belief that is herbicide damage.  I cover my tomato plants when I spray my lawn with a hand sprayer.  Even on days with no wind, the invisible vapor can damage these fickle plants.

I did not experience any of these symptoms this year, and I am using the exact same soil, with the same grass clippings as mulch from my lawn.  I wait one month before bagging my clippings after I spray.  I thought it was in the soil, but it seems fine this year.

If you wait long enough, they might come out of it and give you a crop late in the season.  Mine did.

Comment: Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Good clear question & information. Yes, something seems to have messed them up, green is ok, they seem adequately watered, dont seem wilted. soil.If they can take it, try watering them a bit more.

Also, if theyve been fertilized recently, maybe try skim that off & replace that soil with good plain soil, and water well. too much nutrient can overwhelm them, and reducing the nutrient could reduce combined effects. Its possible they were downwind from something. And maybe check around the roots, ants or something could be messing up the roots.

Comment: Thank you for responding!